# Google Drive Service Initialization Using GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow (How to get Refresh Token?)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, google-drive-api

I have a web application running on web server IIS, so to initialize service we need GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow instead of GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.

What should be passed in `HttpClientInitializer` when creating a service object?

```
    var flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
                        {
                            ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
                            {
                                ClientId = _clientId,
                                ClientSecret = _clientSecret
                            },
                            Scopes = UserAccountCreds.SCOPES,
                            DataStore = new FileDataStore(@"C:\GoogleDriveViewer\DataStore", true)
                        });  

UserCredential credentials = new UserCredential(flow, "user", token); // HOW DO YOU GET REFRESH TOKEN
                    DriveService service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                    {
                        HttpClientInitializer = , // HELP NEEDED HERE
                        ApplicationName = "Drive API Sample",
                    });
```

Comment: try flow but why are you using GoogleAuthorizationFlow and not GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker?

Comment: @DalmTo: When I use GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker in installed apps, it works. But when I host on IIS, it hangs forever and doesn't proceed. So on reading several SO posts, I cam e across GoogleAuthorizationFlow that I am using above. But this requires refresh token, that I don't know where to get from.  Also, just wanted to thank you as I am able to get this much understanding following ur tutorials. They have been of great help

Comment: If you get GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow working please post it I have never seen it used.    I always use GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker

Comment: @DalmTo: I couldn't get GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow working. Could you tell me how I can use GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker when my app is on IIS as website? I checked this SO post which had similar problem as mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22598348/googlewebauthorizationbroker-in-mvc-for-google-drive-access

Comment: Any hints here? I am still stuck here..

Comment: Did you managed to get it worked?

Comment: @ManojSethi Sorry, I don't remember at all. Been a while now but check this if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390197/how-to-create-a-instance-of-usercredential-if-i-already-have-the-value-of-access.