# How to create a instance of UserCredential if I already have the value of Access Token?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-api-dotnet-client, google-plus-domains

So I have this code 
My question is how do I configure the **UserCredential** if I'm already authenticated via OAuth?

The current scenario is the code will display another login page redirecting to google. Since I'm already authenticated via OAuth using asp.net MVC and I already have the token how to I get rid of the **GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker** and directly pass the token?

```
string[] scopes = new string[] {PlusService.Scope.PlusLogin,
                                             PlusService.Scope.UserinfoEmail,
                                             PlusService.Scope.UserinfoProfile};

UserCredential credential = 
GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets
{
    ClientId = "xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    ClientSecret = "xxxx"
},
    scopes,
    Environment.UserName,
    CancellationToken.None,
    new FileDataStore("Store")).Result;

PlusService service = new PlusService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "ArcaneChatV2",
});

PeopleResource.ListRequest listPeople = service.People.List("me", PeopleResource.ListRequest.CollectionEnum.Visible);
listPeople.MaxResults = 10;
PeopleFeed peopleFeed = listPeople.Execute();
var people = new List<Person>();
```

I'm just new to this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Assuming you already have the tokens you can do the following

```
string[] scopes = new string[] {
    PlusService.Scope.PlusLogin,
    PlusService.Scope.UserinfoEmail,
    PlusService.Scope.UserinfoProfile
};

var flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
{
    ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
    {
        ClientId = "xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        ClientSecret = "xxxx"
    },
    Scopes = scopes,
    DataStore = new FileDataStore("Store")
});

var token = new TokenResponse { 
    AccessToken = "[your_access_token_here]",
    RefreshToken = "[your_refresh_token_here]"
};

var credential = new UserCredential(flow, Environment.UserName, token);
```

Then you can pass your credentials to the service's initializer

Reference [Google API Client Libraries > .NET > OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc)

Comment: Just a follow up question @Nkosi how to set the refresh token in UserCredential? credential.Token.RefreshToken = "[your_access_token_here]" is that the right way? Because I kept getting "The access token has expired but we can't refresh it".

Comment: @PrinceJea. You include the refresh token when you create the `TokenResponse`. GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow will get a new access token based on your refresh token and client secrets.

Comment: how to get the refresh token exactly? This is what I've tried **context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:google:refreshtoken", context.RefreshToken, ClaimValueTypes.String, "Google"));** I'm still getting errors.

Comment: Did you read any of the reference material I linked to? I think I quoted something in your other question http://stackoverflow.com/a/38432284/5233410

Comment: Yes I'm reading it for days lol. I'm just stuck on getting user circles right now. I've done it on facebook but the google api gave me headaches.

Comment: OK. Do you get a refresh token when you authenticate your users?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117589/discussion-between-prince-jea-and-nkosi).

Comment: why there is a client secret needed if I am doing a native android authentication, I dont have client secret. This is only for web applications i believe

Comment: If you don't have the refresh token, but you are getting an error indicating your token has expired then you need to set the ExpiresInSeconds property on the TokenResponse to something which seems to prevent the need for a RefreshToken if you are doing a once off server call like I was. I found that 60 seconds didn't work, but larger numbers did. It's not very scientific I know.

Answer (score 7):

We can create `GoogleCredential` directly from the access token and use it instead of `UserCredential` as well. I just think it might be helpful for someone. Here is a code snippet of `GmailService` initialization:

```
GoogleCredential cred = GoogleCredential.FromAccessToken(accessToken);
GmailService service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer {HttpClientInitializer = cred});
```

Comment: This works, but do you know how can I refresh this token?

Comment: It was VERY helpful! Just what I needed, thx!