# How to resolve 'The access token has expired but we can't refresh it' in MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm currently working on **Google Api** which aims to get the circles of a loggedin person.I already have the **access token** but the problem is whenever I try to run my code it returns this exception

> **The access token has expired but we can't refresh it**

How do I resolve this issue?

```
var claimsforUser = await UserManager.GetClaimsAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
var access_token = claimsforUser.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "urn:google:accesstoken").Value;

string[] scopes = new string[] {PlusService.Scope.PlusLogin,
                                PlusService.Scope.UserinfoEmail,
                                PlusService.Scope.UserinfoProfile};

var flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
    {

        ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
        {
            ClientId = "xx-xx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
            ClientSecret = "v-xx",
        },
        Scopes = scopes,
        DataStore = new FileDataStore("Store"),
    });

var token = new TokenResponse { AccessToken = access_token, ExpiresInSeconds=50000};
var credential = new UserCredential(flow, Environment.UserName, token);


PlusService service = new PlusService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "ArcaneChatV2",
});

PeopleResource.ListRequest listPeople = service.People.List("me", PeopleResource.ListRequest.CollectionEnum.Visible);
listPeople.MaxResults = 10;
PeopleFeed peopleFeed = listPeople.Execute();
var people = new List<Person>();


while (peopleFeed.Items != null)
{

    foreach (Person item in peopleFeed.Items)
    {
        people.Add(item);
    }
    if (peopleFeed.NextPageToken == null)
    {
        break;
    }
    listPeople.PageToken = peopleFeed.NextPageToken;

    // Execute and process the next page request
    peopleFeed = listPeople.Execute();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you already have the refresh token, you include the refresh token when you create the `TokenResponse`

```cs
var token = new TokenResponse { 
    AccessToken = access_token, 
    RefreshToken = refresh_token
};
```

**[User Credentials](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#user-credentials)**

> UserCredential is a thread-safe helper class for using an access token
>   to access protected resources. **An access token typically expires after
>   1 hour, after which you will get an error if you try to use it**.
>
> UserCredential and AuthorizationCodeFlow take care of automatically
>   "refreshing" the token, which simply means getting a new access token.
>   This is done using a long-lived refresh token, which you receive along
>   with the access token if you use the access_type=offline parameter
>   during the authorization code flow.
>
> In most applications, it is advisable to store the credential's access
>   token and refresh token in persistent storage. Otherwise, you will
>   need to present the end user with an authorization page in the browser
>   every hour, because the access token expires an hour after you've
>   received it.