# How to implement Google Drive API with .Net Core MVC Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, google-drive-api, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have been trying to get Google Drive API working with [.Net Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) (which has google Oauth2 built in)

I have tried following [this](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-asp.net-mvc) tutorial. But it is not for .Net Core. How would I use .Net Core Identity to be able to access google drive after they log in?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need your Google console app to have the Drive API enabled then you'll need to add the correct scope to your Identity configuration in `startup.cs`. This will ensure that when your user logs in they get the correct scope assigned to their login token(s).

An example, if you want to read files and/or file META from Drive you might have:
`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly`

See here for scopes: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/about-auth

Here is a sample of how that might look:

```
        services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
        {
            googleOptions.ClientId = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID";
            googleOptions.ClientSecret = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET";
            googleOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly");
            googleOptions.SaveTokens = true;
            ...
        });
```

From here your user will have an AccessToken and RefreshToken returned when they log in. You can use this (along with their email address) to access their Google Drive.

I have a service which I use to make various requests to the API.

Comment: thanks for the info! this is really helping. Can you help me use those tokens to create a UserCredential so that I can access the API? I found this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390197/how-to-create-a-instance-of-usercredential-if-i-already-have-the-value-of-access But I am unsure how to get the tokens, and what to do with the Datastore. Thanks,

Comment: an example on how to initialize a drive service instance using the logged in idenitity user (logged in with an identity Google external login) would be much aprreciated indeed :)