# Google API authorization access denied while generating token

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-oauth, azure-web-app-service, google-authentication, drive

I'm having some issues with google API while generating the token. The code works fine in the local machine but the publish version gives "Access is denied" error. I know that must be something related with the folder's permissions, but I don't know how to solve it. Actually our authorization function is like this:

```
public static DriveService AuthenticateOauth(string clientId, string clientSecret, string userName)
{
       String folder = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/App_Data/MyGoogleStorage/");

       string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive };

       // here is where we Request the user to give us access, or use the Refresh Token that was previously stored in %AppData%
       UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets { ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = clientSecret }
               , scopes
               , userName 
               , CancellationToken.None
               , new FileDataStore(folder)).Result;

       DriveService service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
       {
           HttpClientInitializer = credential,
           ApplicationName = "Drive API",
       });
       return service;
}
```

The website is written in ASP NET MVC 5 and is hosted in Azure websites.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: did you set up the correct credentials for your Production environment on the [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials)?

Comment: Yes, I have them in the code and is working fine locally. And I suppose  that in the publish version must be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided to use only my own drive account. So I created a token and I'm using it all the time. I followed these topics:

1.- Create a token for Google Drive API: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19766913/4965910

2.- Add Google API to MVC properly and use our token:
[GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker in MVC For Google Drive Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22598348/googlewebauthorizationbroker-in-mvc-for-google-drive-access?rq=1)

You must be careful, is easy to get stuck in some steps.

This only woks for ASP NET MVC applications with one drive account. I know is not solves the problem directly, this way is avoided it. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi 
I am having the same problem. Did you ever get this to work for all users using oauth?

Comment: If you are implying if this works with different drive accounts, one per user, the answer is: I don't know.  I didn't solve the problem, I avoided using only my own account.

Answer (score 0):

> The code works fine in the local machine but the publish version gives "Access is denied" error.

I have a same issue after I deploy the web application to Azure websites.

[image]

I refer to “Web applications (ASP.NET MVC)” section from [this article](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc) to get user Credential and use DriveService, and I find it works fine on Azure websites.