# nodejs server auth to Office365 Outlook Calendar without any window

Tags: node.js, outlook, google-cloud-platform, office365

I developed an app using Firebase and Google Calendar, now i want substitute Google Calendar with Office365 Outlook Calendar.

The app is composed by a "phone app" made in Cordova that connects to a "server app" made in NodeJS. The "server app" uses a "Google Service Account" to add users to some calendars they don't own and grant them write permission. Using a service account was the only option to do this, due to its high privileges and the fact it doesn't require to open any login or authorize window.

I never used MS services and reading the docs it seems it's a mess because some services use a version of the API and some other use another one.

How can i authorize the "server app" in an equivalent way of the google's service account, so i can do the same thing? (add users to some calendars they don't own and grant them write permission).

Thanks.

Comment: Did you checked this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22598348/googlewebauthorizationbroker-in-mvc-for-google-drive-access

Comment: I need to use Microsoft's services, not Google's ones